# Why is the Facebook Like button causing an error when using WordPress permalinks?

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

For about a week, the "Like" button worked fine on my posts (single.php) with `href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'`, but it suddenly started causing the following error message:

> The identifier of the application specified in the "fb: app_id" is not
>   allowed on the field. You must configure the database connection for
>   your application domain with the prefix:

A few things to note:

- My website is a WordPress site
- The opengraph in my website is fine
- The Like button code is correct

What can I do to correct this?

Comment: the code you used would be helpful here, also make sure you have not installed any plugins which would add duplicate meta tags to your install.

Answer (score 2):

That error could be thrown if the app_id in the meta tag is a page id or incorrect.

Also in your application settings, make sure to set up the site url and domain.  The like button will need to be on same domain as set in app settings.

```
<head>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="YourAppId"/>
</head>
```

Comment: i installed a plugin sharethis , is make automaticaly facebook opengraph

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/) > applications and select the application for that site!
In **AppDomains** you should put your site adress
in **Mobile Web** if you dont have a adress for mobile you can put the normal adress from your site if you dont have a adress for mobile (but you have to fill this one)

Press Save

refresh your site and try the like button :)

this worked for me :)